# Should commas *always* be followed by spaces?

Tags: commas, typography, style-manuals, spacing, exceptions

When teaching and proofreading, I often come across examples of commas without spaces following them (e.g. "London,UK" or "apples,oranges,bananas").  In addition to correcting these, I would like to clearly cite and explain the rule.

I believe the rule is that a comma should **always** be followed by a space, but would like to confirm this with a reliable citeable source, and have a complete list of exceptions.  The only exceptions I can think of right now are:

- before a closing quotation mark: *"Where," he wondered, "could it be?"* 
  When this exception applies, the space follows the closing quote.
- Within a large number: *The factory produced 3,252,975 widgets last month.*
- in the code portion of programming, where English grammatical rules don't quite apply
- in Tweets, telegrams, or similar settings with character constraints that lead to relaxation of grammatical rules

Are there reliable sources for this rule and/or other exceptions?

Comment: I agree totally; punctuation and to a greater degree orthography are often style choices, but this one has been a standard formula for decades or above. In spite of Strunk and White's often deserved poor press, the rules [Michelle X](https://mixed-upfiles.com/comma-rules-to-teach-secondary/) (and 'Word' advisors) echo are the same as yours and mine. // Please note that 'grammar' is seen as disjoint from punctuation (and certainly orthography) on ELU. // I'd also not use a comma in say "Where" read the sign "do you think you're going?"

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Retagged. While I *would* use a comma in that last example, I think we'd agree that if present, the comma would precede the closing quote with no intervening space.

Comment: Putting spaces in numbers can be confusing: "There are 86,400 seconds in a day" is clearer to me than "There are 86, 400 seconds in a day."

Comment: @jejorda2 I agree. Did you catch that the numbers example was in a list of **exceptions?**

Comment: @wbt I missed that you added the second bullet point in an edit-  You can safely ignore my comment!

Comment: @jejorda2 I prefer the more modern convention "There are 86 400 seconds in a day" (pretend that's a 'small space'). It looks clear, and (maths being a universal language) doesn't lead to ambiguities when those who use a decimal comma read it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth but it could lead to ambiguity where it isn't clear whether it's a single five-digit figure or a two-digit figure followed by a three-digit figure.  Those who use decimal commas should learn how to format numbers correctly in English just as we who use decimal points should learn how to format numbers correctly in whatever other languages we might learn.

Comment: @phoog You'd better look at what 'English' actually advocates.  CMoS 9.56 advises:

<< In the International System of Units (SI units), thin, fixed spaces rather than commas are normally used to mark off groups of three digits [hence] 3 426 869 ... >> I used to teach maths to beyond A-Level.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth and that section follows 9.55, which talks about commas in numbers.  Besides, the CMoS hardly speaks for "English."  Can you name a non-technical publication that uses spaces?

Comment: [Robert Bringhurst](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138047/when-writing-large-numbers-should-a-comma-be-inserted) himself (and he, if anyone did, wrote the book) recommends the use of the small space separator. The comma itself can lead to ambiguity ("Doses? We have 650, 500 of them ready for use.")

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, comma is often followed by a space but that isn't the case with commas used in numerals, or when followed by a closing quotation mark. Numerals follows mathematical rules not grammar rules is the prime reason, while the reason of missing space between closing quotation mark & the preceding comma is simply because of old standardised grammar rules.

> He said, "I am going to school." [Note there's no space between full
>   stop & closing quotes but there's a space between comma & opening
>   quotes]
>
> "I am going to school," He said. [Note there's no space between comma
>   & closing quotes]

Also check [this website](https://www.englishclub.com/writing/punctuation-comma.htm) for almost all examples of proper comma usage.

Also, in regard to social media platforms, these aren't formal modes of communication and thus, grammar rules don't necessarily apply to them.